# Merge Null Values in Merge Command

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, sql-update, sql-insert

i must merge multible database tables in a node js windows service.
so i decided to write a method that creates a sql string for this.

here is my method:

```
function createSQLString(targetTable, sourceTable, columns){
let sql = "MERGE " + targetTable + " AS TARGET USING " + sourceTable + " AS SOURCE \n";

switch (sourceTable) {
    //.....some other cases.....
    case 'communications':
        sql += "ON (" +
            " TARGET.[id] = SOURCE.[id]" +
            " AND TARGET.[business_partner_id] = SOURCE.[business_partner_id]" +
            " AND TARGET.[fiscalYear] = SOURCE.[fiscalYear]" +
            ") \n";
        break;
    default:
        // other stuff
}

// if row was found and values are not equal
sql += "WHEN MATCHED AND (";
    columns.forEach(column => {
        sql += "SOURCE.[" + column.COLUMN_NAME + "] <> TARGET.[" + column.COLUMN_NAME + "] OR ";
    })
    sql = sql.substring(0, sql.length -4) + "\n";
sql += ") THEN UPDATE SET ";
    columns.forEach(column => {
        sql += "TARGET.[" + column.COLUMN_NAME + "] = SOURCE.[" + column.COLUMN_NAME + "],"
    })
    sql = sql.substring(0, sql.length -1) + "\n";

// if no match in target insert
sql += "WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT (";
    columns.forEach(column => {
        sql += "[" + column.COLUMN_NAME + "], ";
    })
    sql = sql.substring(0, sql.length -2) + "\n";
sql += ") VALUES ("
    columns.forEach(column => {
        sql += "SOURCE.[" + column.COLUMN_NAME + "], ";
    })
    sql = sql.substring(0, sql.length -2) + "\n";
sql += ")\n"

// if there is a record in target but not in source
sql += "WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE \n THEN DELETE;"
return sql;
}
```

this method and the created sql string works nice, expect in one case.
if the value in the source table column is `NULL` the target will not be updated.
here is a screenshot for that case (table 1 target, table 2 source):
[image]

why isnt it be updating and how to solve it?

edit: here is generated sql string:

```
MERGE communication AS TARGET USING communication_cache AS SOURCE 
ON (
TARGET.[id] = SOURCE.[id] AND 
TARGET.[fiscalYear] = SOURCE.[fiscalYear] AND 
TARGET.[clientId] = SOURCE.[clientId]
) 
WHEN MATCHED AND (
SOURCE.[id] <> TARGET.[id] OR 
SOURCE.[address_type] <> TARGET.[address_type] OR 
SOURCE.[is_correspondence_address] <> TARGET.[is_correspondence_address] OR 
SOURCE.[is_main_post_office_box_address] <> TARGET. 
[is_main_post_office_box_address] OR 
SOURCE.[is_main_street_address] <> TARGET.[is_main_street_address] OR 
SOURCE.[is_management_address] <> TARGET.[is_management_address] OR 
SOURCE.[business_partner_id] <> TARGET.[business_partner_id] OR 
SOURCE.[fiscalYear] <> TARGET.[fiscalYear]
) 
THEN UPDATE SET 
TARGET.[id] = SOURCE.[id],
TARGET.[address_type] = SOURCE.[address_type],
TARGET.[is_correspondence_address] = SOURCE.[is_correspondence_address],
TARGET.[is_main_post_office_box_address] = SOURCE. 
[is_main_post_office_box_address],
TARGET.[is_main_street_address] = SOURCE.[is_main_street_address],
TARGET.[is_management_address] = SOURCE.[is_management_address],
TARGET.[business_partner_id] = SOURCE.[business_partner_id],
TARGET.[fiscalYear] = SOURCE.[fiscalYear]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT (
[id], [address_type], [is_correspondence_address], 
[is_main_post_office_box_address], [is_main_street_address], 
[is_management_address], [business_partner_id], [fiscalYear]
) VALUES (SOURCE.[id], SOURCE.[address_type], SOURCE. 
[is_correspondence_address], SOURCE.[is_main_post_office_box_address], 
SOURCE.[is_main_street_address], SOURCE.[is_management_address], SOURCE. 
[business_partner_id], SOURCE.[fiscalYear]
)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
THEN DELETE
```

Comment: can you tell us the final SQL string that is formed? That will help to analyse better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NULL is a special case in any RDBMS.

When you write below condition in *WHEN MATCHED* clause:

```
SOURCE.[is_correspondence_address] <> TARGET.[is_correspondence_address] OR
```

it is not considering NULL for comparison - any comparison with NULL results into NULL.

If you want to handle NULL in comparison, you can write below clause (assumming is_correspondence_address is VARCHAR/NVARCHAR datatype):

```
    ISNULL(SOURCE.[is_correspondence_address],'NOTDEFINED') 
      <> ISNULL(TARGET.[is_correspondence_address], 'NOTDEFINED') OR
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can fix the problem by adding anonther condition to check for nullity of the offending column, I would recommend simply dispensing the `AND` condition to the `WHEN MATCHED` clause.

For once, this vastly simplifies the query, and does not change the results.

As for performance, I see many situations where this will not degrade performance, or might even improve it: performing all these `OR` checks on every row is expensive, and rewriting the values regardless whether they changed or not may be just faster. Also, the way the `MERGE` statement is built, you rewrite all values if any of them changed anyway.

Another benefit is that this covers all edge cases as regard to other columns possibly having `nul` values (while, on the other hand, you would need to modify again the existing query to handle that).

So:

```
MERGE communication AS t USING communication_cache AS s
ON (t.[id] = s.[id] AND t.[fiscalYear] = s.[fiscalYear] AND t.[clientId] = s.[clientId]) 
WHEN MATCHED 
THEN UPDATE SET 
    t.[id] = s.[id],
    t.[address_type] = s.[address_type],
    t.[is_correspondence_address] = s.[is_correspondence_address],
    t.[is_main_post_office_box_address] = s. 
    [is_main_post_office_box_address],
    t.[is_main_street_address] = s.[is_main_street_address],
    t.[is_management_address] = s.[is_management_address],
    t.[business_partner_id] = s.[business_partner_id],
    t.[fiscalYear] = s.[fiscalYear]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT (
    [id], [address_type], [is_correspondence_address], 
    [is_main_post_office_box_address], [is_main_street_address], 
    [is_management_address], [business_partner_id], [fiscalYear]
) VALUES (
    s.[id], s.[address_type], s.[is_correspondence_address], 
    s.[is_main_post_office_box_address], s.[is_main_street_address], 
    s.[is_management_address], s. [business_partner_id], s.[fiscalYear]
)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE
```

Note that I used shorter table aliases (`s` and `t`), which makes the query shorter, and somehow more readable.